# catching user input to run scripts

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to write a small bash script using mac OS TextEdit that will catch a user input in terminal and based on the file type stipulated in the command line albeit (jpg or gif) iterate through a directory on my desktop named `dir1`, pull all files of that filetype and place such in a new directory called `dir2`

i.e The user types jpg into the terminal and the script kicks into life and pulls all of the jpg files situated in `dir1` and places such in `dir2`

What is the leanest and least convoluted way of achieving this conscious that I am new to shell scripting.

I am about to reach for the meds. What can I do to the below code to get it to work.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo “Good Morning, Please enter your file type for sorting [ENTER]:”
read $FILE
if [[ $file == *.jpg ]]; then
    mv ~/DIR1/*jpg* ~/Users/christopherdorman/desktop/dir2/
echo “your files have been successfully processed”
fi
```

Comment: You need to use $FILE in your if statement since bash is case sensitive.

Comment: i deployed the $ but i am getting an error message that states "line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple confusions here regarding bash variables and syntax.  You need to use `fi` to close your if statement instead of `done`. Also, you need to capitalize the variable in your if statement, since bash is case sensitive. I believe this is what you are looking for (assuming your input is "jpg" or "gif"):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo “Good Morning, Please enter your file type for sorting [ENTER]:”
read FILE
if [[ $FILE == "jpg" ]]; then
    mv ~/DIR1/*jpg* ~/Users/christopherdorman/desktop/dir2/
    echo “your files have been successfully processed”
fi
```

Comment: joel I think that is helped it along a good bit. I am getting now.mv: rename /Users/christopherdorman/DIR1/*jpg* to /Users/christopherdorman/Users/christopherdorman/desktop/dir2/